# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this PHP code that produces a warning:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() php wordpress
```

Here is the code:

```
<?php   
    $post_status1  = 'publish'; 
    $post_type1 = 'page';
    $featucat = "about";
    $featucount = "1";

    $my_query = new WP_Query('post_status='. $post_status1 .'&post_type='. $post_type1.'');  
    if ($my_query->have_posts()){
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

            $front_values = get_post_custom_values('Homepage_Blog_01p', get_the_ID());
            foreach ( $front_values as $front_key => $result_value ) {
                if($result_value == 'about') {
?>

                    <div class="thewidgets">
                        <?php
                        $description_values = get_post_custom_values('Description_Field', get_the_ID());
                        foreach ( $description_values as $description_key => $description_value ) {
                            echo $description_value;

                        }
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Read the whole post" class="rm">Read More</a>
                    </div>
    <?php } } endwhile; } ?>
```

Here is the full error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 
D:\PROGRAM FILES\wamp\www\westchester\wp-content\themes\
computerrepair\footer.php on line 22"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$front_values` is not an array if you're getting that. Check its contents, and if it's legitimately not an array at times (for example, if `get_post_custom_values` returns `null` when there aren't any results), account for it by wrapping the `foreach` in an `if(is_array($front_values)) {` conditional.

Comment: thanks for the answer, base on what you said, I added `if(is_array($front_values)) {` that wraps `foreach ( $front_values as $front_key => $result_value ) { if($result_value == 'homepage1') {` and the error is gone but yet no content is showing :(

Comment: If nothing is showing, `get_post_custom_values('Homepage_Blog_01p', get_the_ID())` isn't returning anything. Check its output by `print_r($front_values)`.

Comment: yes, I tried `print_r($front_values)` it and nothing has been outputted so I could conclude that it isnt really returning anything, so what should I do to make it show? any idea?

Comment: thank you! i already figured it out, thanks for the guidance :)

Answer (score 0):

### How to reproduce this PHP warning:

Put this in `a.php`:

```
<?php
$skipper = "abcd";
foreach ($skipper as $item){       //warning happens on this line.
    print "ok";
}

?>
```

Prints:

```
eric@dev ~ $ php a.php
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 
/var/www/sandbox/eric/code/php/run06/a.php on line 3
PHP Stack trace:
```

The warning means exactly what it says.  You passed a parameter into the foreach structure which could not be evaluated in the foreach.  Before the foreach loop, ensure that the first parameter is a structure that the foreach can handle.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Add this code in the head tag. I think it will solve your warning -  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp64\www\development\wp-includes\script-loader.php on line 2652